# Symfony 5.3 User Login by username or email

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony5, symfony-security

I am porting a Symfony 3 project to Symfony 5.3.
I have to get rid of the fosuserbundle but need to have the existing users remaining able to login by username OR email. Users have to be able to choose if they input username/password or email/password.
I created a User class and login form as explained in the basic tutorials

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-create-your-user-class

and

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

I added a username property to the userclass (although the maker bundle autogenerated a deprecation hint for the "getUsername"-getter: "since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead") and migrated the user-data from old DB to new DB.
Login now works fine with the credentials stored in the DB - but only login by email not by username.

What am I missing to make the autogenerated login form / auth-provider work with username too?

Comment: Just to clarify, your want users to be able to log in with either email OR username?

Comment: Yeah right. In the existing DB email and username is stored and the still productively running app enables users to login by username or email - free of choice. I need to keep this available.

Comment: Okay.  There are two basic approaches.  You can configure a [chained user provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#chain-user-provider) which involves configuring a username provider and a email provider and then chaining them together. A second approach is to make your own custom user provider (also documented by the previous link) which allows you to build your own query with an OR condition.  I personally like making a custom user provider but either approach works.

Comment: The chained user provider setup seems to work. However I get stuck a bit later by indirect calls from templates (which I am trying to migrate) to "roles"-functions from the fosuserbundle like addRole(). How would I replace those functions which seem to completely not live inside the User class anymore (while a getRoles() function still exists...)?

Comment: The User class generated via make:user only the contains the methods needed to implement UserInterface.  The rest of the stuff like addRole is strictly up to you.  If you need additional help and can't find it by searching then opening a new specific question might be best.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand that everything beyond the autogenerated scope is up to me. But isn't role handling sth which should be handled by the security components in one way or another? Or could I just copy the addRole(), removeRole(), ... functions from fosuser (which just add/drop roles to the DB) and stick to happily using them...? :-)

Comment: All the security system cares about is that the users have roles.  It has no interest in how they are assigned or managed.  But yes, using your fos user base class as a starting point is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the code that you have referenced from the Symfony documentation in a way that will suite your requirements. As it is, it only allows for an email login, but you need to additionally add the possibility for the username.

Start by modifying the login form to allow for a username. So in the example from the tutorial we will need to change the type and possibly the name to something like:

```
<label for="inputEmailOrUsername">Email or Username</label>
<input type="text" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email_or_username" id="inputEmailOrUsername" class="form-control" required autofocus>
```

Next up is the LoginFormAuthenticator (or whatever it is called for you). Modify the `authenticate` method to suite the changes in the login form

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email_or_username' => $request->request->get('email_or_username'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
    ];
    
    ...
}
```

And modify the `getUser` method to look for either an email or username:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider): ?User
{
    ...

    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findByEmailOrUsername($credentials['email_or_username']);

    // ...
}
```

As you can see I have replaced the `findOneBy` call to the repository with a non-existing method called `findByEmailOrUsername`. Go ahead and create this method in your UserRepository class to be something like the following:

```
public function findByEmailOrUsername(string $emailOrUsername)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.email = :emailOrUsername')
        ->orWhere('u.username = :emailOrUsername')
        ->setParameter('emailOrUsername', $emailOrUsername)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

This should be the general working prototype of the code in order to allow for a login with a username or an email address. Please take care of validating the login form input field yourself.

---

**UPDATE** - *to suite latest Symfony5 Authenticator changes*:

For reference: [Using the new Authenticator-based security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html)

Instead of using the `getCredentials` and `getUser` methods (they do not exist anymore), you should use the `authenticate` method, by supplying a UserLoader as a second parameter to the UserBadge class in order to fullfill your requirement.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
{
    $emailOrUsername = $request->request->get('email_or_username');
    // ... get the rest of the parameters from the input bag

    // ... validate no parameter is empty

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($emailOrUsername, function ($userIdentifier) {
            return $this->userRepository->findByEmailOrUsername($userIdentifier);
        }),
        // ... rest of the parameters
    );
}
```

Comment: Bits of this are correct but ultimately won't work.  Someone coming from FOSUserBundle is not going to have a guard authenticator class so most of your code won't make sense.  All that is really needed is to adjust the UserProvider.

Comment: What do you mean by bits of this? Which part in particular is not correct? The user mentioned that he got rid of the FOSUserBundle and aftewards implemented the two links mentioned in the question - meaning he tried to implement a new user class and a form login authenticator. Hence, my answer took these things into cosideration.

Comment: If you want to assume the use of an authentication class then you should also assume it's using the new classes.  Which mean no getUser or getCredentials methods.  Ultimately, it's the job of the User Provider to provide a user.

Comment: I did implement the posted links. User setup ist new. Data though comes from existing DB (including emails and usernames that have both to be usable for login). I do not use anything from fosuserbundle anymore. The generated LoginFormAuthenticator does not have getCredentials or getUser methods.

Comment: I updated my answer to suite for the latest Symfony updates, please check it out.

Comment: @Darko Your updated answer is closer but you still seem a bit focused on using a repository method.  To me it just makes more sense to configure a UserProvider and be done with it.

Comment: The answer is closer to what? The repository method is needed in any case, no matter whether you use a UserProvider or an Authenticator, you still need to tell the database how to load the user. The documentation that you referenced in your upper comments to the user still uses a repository method.